# Сохранить состояние табов в React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

Помогите пожалуйста сохранить состояние табов, нужно чтобы при переключении сохранялись действия пользователя, я пока не придумал как это сделать

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import Dashboard from './components/Dashboard/Dashboard';
import Header from './components/Header/Header';
import MapView from './components/MapView/MapView';

import cls from './App.module.css'

const App = () => {

const [activeTab, setActiveTab] = useState(1)

const tabs = [
    {id : 1, name : 'Tasks', position: 'left'},
    {id : 2, name : 'View', position: 'left'},
    {id : 3, name : 'Profile', position: 'right'}
]

return (
    <div className={cls.app}>
        <Header 
            activeTab={activeTab} 
            tabs={tabs}
            setActive={setActiveTab}
        />
        {
            activeTab === 1 ? <Dashboard /> :
            activeTab === 2 ? <MapView /> : null
        }
    </div>
);
}

export default App;
```

При переключении табов идёт ререндеринг, как этого можно избежать?

Comment: Можете детализировать ваш вопрос? Какого именно поведения вы хотите достичь? Заголовок, текст и сам вопрос расходятся...

Comment: @SwaD Переключение табов без пеперисовки комплнентов (чтобы на вкладках были сохранены действия пользователя, например текст в инпутах или развёрнут ли список). Сейчас они просто перерисовываются заново. На данный момент мне удалось этого добиться используя useRef для получения ноды и вручную менять заначение hidden, но не думаю что это хорошее решение

Comment: Сохранять изменения в хранилище приложения(redux, localStore) и при монтировании компонентов подтягивать эти значения или вынести данные в компонент App и передавать их пропсами. Как у вас реализовано, компоненты отмонтируются при переключении, следовательно, все забывается.